# Educational Community License, Version 2.0 (ECL-2.0)

Tags: open-source, licensing

in Educational Community License, Version 2.0, what is the meaning of the following: "Any patent license granted hereby with respect to contributions by an individual employed by an institution or organization is limited to patent claims where the individual that is the author of the Work is also the inventor of the patent claims licensed, and where the organization or institution has the right to grant such license under applicable grant and research funding agreements. No other express or implied licenses are granted"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing and legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks to be pretty clear...

You cannot patent the work others contributed to the project.

You can patent your own work so long as the organization approves it.

The organization can only approve it if whoever is paying the bills allows it.

No other licenses are allowed, and the license cannot be changed.

~

*my disclaimer*: I'm not a lawyer.

Comment: Thanks for reply. So can I modify in the original work then sell the whole work without acknowledging the author of the work?

Comment: given the spirit of the above clause, I would think there probably is something else preventing you from doing so. I would imagine there is a lot more to this license than what you have posted above.

Comment: and, if you are asking about modifying a small portion then selling the entire thing as your own, then no, absolutely not and that would surely get you into trouble. there's multiple things at play, copyright and the license agreement. both are legal. copyright is always with the original author, unless expressly assigned to someone else (in a university/education scenario, likely assigned to the institution). so you would still be stealing someone else's work and claiming it to be yours, since you did not write the entire thing.

Comment: if you are looking for a license for a new project that allows you to do whatever you want with the codebase, even sell it, modify it, etc.. . you probably are interested in the Apache license, MIT license, BSD license, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. This is ECL v2.0. It is similar to Apache v2 license. This clause is only added to ECL v2.0 (point no. 3). I know that Apache license permit that but I don't know if this clause prevent that or not.

Comment: I took a look at the license and, upon a glace-over, it *seems* to allow redistribution so long as you meet the requirements (they list them, including attribute all original work to the original authors, prominently display the license, etc). It may be possible, but it would take a deeper review of the license to be sure.